# Is there a function in Matlab to read your computer's audio in and store data in near real time?

Tags: matlab, audio

Would anyone know if there is a way in MATLAB to read from your computer's audio in and store the data into a pre-allocated array? If so, what is the function or the path to do so?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's very simple. check these two links

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/audiorecorder.html

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/162428

Comment: Cool, this will give me the start I need. Now I just have to see if it will recognize my sound card driver. :)